# How can I embed a video in a drupal page that is remotely hosted in Amazon s3 cloudfront?

Tags: media

When I try to embed a video in a drupal page that is hosted remotely on an Amazon s3 server, I get the following error message:

"Could not find a video provider to handle the given URL"

I have the Video Embed Field, Video Embed Media, Video Embed WYSIWIG modules enabled, but still cannot get this to work.

The URL of my video has this form, where the x's represent the directory path to the videos.
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.mp4

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Those modules only know how to embed videos from particular providers (Youtube, Vimeo, Facebook, etc). They actually parse the URL and check that it contains "youtube" or "vimeo" or whatever. The modules won't work with arbitrary URLs, S3 or not.

A couple of potential solutions:

1. Use a more generic module, for example [VideoJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs), which should theoretically let you embed a video from anywhere.
2. Write your own handler for Video Embed Field which knows how to embed videos from S3. You'll presumably have to find a JS library which can play the video from Amazon, and integrate that as part of it. Writing the handler itself is pretty easy, it's just a matter of a hook or two and a few functions. The code for the existing handlers makes it pretty obvious what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll start with VideoJS to see if I can make that work.